# Hosting website and nginx on heroku and blog at wordpress.com under same domain

Tags: wordpress, nginx, heroku, dns, reverse-proxy

My goal is to have under the same domain a Rails web application running on Heroku (website) - responding to requests on root (*www.example.com*) and a blog hosted on wordpress.com - responding to request on /blog path (*www.example.com/blog*).
Currently heroku manages the certificate on my domain.com (web dyno) and I also have a wordpress issued certificate for my blog.domain.com.

1. Should I have a SSL certificate managed by Heroku, only on proxy dyno?
2. How should I setup `nginx.conf` to work correctly with SSL?
3. Is it possible to achieve it with wordpress.com? (the non-tech support said it was not)

Since I am hosting on Heroku, I cannot have an IP address to my dyno, so I have to redirect to my domain (already mapped to heroku dns). For the blog part, I wordpress.com does not give me an IP address, also, so I have to use a subdomain (blog.) that I have already mapped and it works fine.

```
# nginx.conf
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen $PORT;

        # listen 443 ssl; # localhost debugging
        # ssl_certificate     localhost.crt; # localhost debugging
        # ssl_certificate_key localhost.key; # localhost debugging

        location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_ssl_server_name on; # To avoid 502 bad gateway

            proxy_set_header Host $host; # If I put this, I stop being redirected to domain.com (URL rewrite) but I face 502 bad gateway issue
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass https://example.com:443;
        }
        location /blog/ {
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass https://blog.example.com:443;
        }
    }
}
```

What I was expecting is to navigate through www.domain.com on both website/blog without any kind of redirection or URL rewrite. What I get is either a redirection (302) with url change OR 502 bad gateway (when I try to use the configuration above) - if I setup 'Host' header.

Comment: Try adding slash: `proxy_pass https://blog.example.com:443/`

Comment: Adding the trailing slash - and commenting the `Host` header - got it working on `localhost` again (Chrome), but when I deployed, I got a redirection anyway. The weird thing is: when I query my localhost with cURL, I got a `< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` `< Server: nginx/1.17.2` `< Location: https://127.0.0.1/blog/`. Why?

Comment: Wow, actually I was cURLing without the trailing slash... But I still have some issues:
1. The connection is not secure (which SSL certificate should I use?).
2. How can I forward both `/blog/` and `/blog`

Comment: 1) You should terminate ssl on nginx, using cert for www.example.com, because that is all your end users see,  2) I guess just use `location /blog {`